# Two CheckListBoxes, user can select an item on any one and get selected item in another?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Here is my scenario:

1. I have a **two checklist-boxes** on Winform  (i.e. **Name and Nickname** checklist boxes)
2. If user selects **Name in first checklist-box** then corresponding **Nickname should get selected automatically in second checklist box**
3. If user selects **Nickname in second checklist-box** then corresponding **Name should get selected automatically in first checklist-box**

Can any one help how to achieve this ?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SelectedIndexChanged event from each checklist-box and search in the items collections from the other checklist-box from the correspondent value. The match you should get it from your database or something like that.

hope it help..